# Unity: List<> OrderBy - inherited property

Tags: c#, list, sorting, unity-game-engine, casting

I have a class:

```
public class ItemObject : ScriptableObject
{
    int id;
    string name;
}
```

and I can sort them by their id like this:

```
sortedItems = new List<GameObject>(allItems.OrderBy(x => x.GetComponent<InventorySlotItem>().item.id));
```

but I also have the child class:

```
public class EquipmentObject : ItemObject
{
    int power;
    int def;
    int spDef;
}
```

is there a way to use the OrderBy method for sorting them by "power" ? I was hoping for some downcasting like:

```
sortedItems = new List<GameObject>(allItems.OrderBy(x => (EquipmentObject)x.GetComponent<InventorySlotItem>().item.power));
```

I tried to downcast in many different ways but nothing worked.

Comment: Can you please provide exactly what has not worked? It didn't compile? Threw error at runtime?

Comment: Also what is `InventorySlotItem` and how it is connected to the classes in question?

Comment: Why are you attempting to convert a `ScriptableObject` to a `GameObject`?

Comment: InventorySlotItem is a UI GameObject that is holding the ScriptableObject (item) 

I want to sort the UI Elements (displaying the item icons) 
I can sort normal items easily but when I try to sort equipment items, it's not compiling saying:

Compiler Error CS1061
ItemObject has no definition for "power"

because only the EquipmentObject : ItemObject has it

Comment: please,  provide content of `InventorySlotItem`

Comment: `public class InventorySlotItem : MonoBehaviour, IClickable
{
    public ItemObject item;
}`

Comment: I fixed it now:

`sortedItems  = new List<GameObject>(sortedItems.OrderBy(x => 
{
    if (x.GetComponent<InventorySlotItem>().item is EquipmentObject equipment)
    {
        return equipment.power;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}));`